# JS Promises: if a handler in a `then` block returns a value vs returning a resolved promise, does the `then` block handle it the same way?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Say I have a function that returns a resolved promise like this:

```
let a = () => {return new Promise(res => res(1))}
```

and then I `then-ify` it like this:

```
a()
.then(val => {return new Promise(res => res(1))})
```

Here the `then` contains a handler that returns a promise resolved with `1`, so the `then` block returns a promise resolved with `1` as well. Is that right?

Then say instead we have this:

```
a()
.then(val => {return 1})
```

The handler returns `1` instead of returning a promise resolved with `1`.

**What I Want To Know:** Does the `then` block return a promise resolved with `1` in both of these scenarios, even though one handler returned a resolved promise and the other just returned a value? In other words, does a `then` block deal with handlers that return promises resolved with a value the same way they deal with handlers that return the value itself?

Comment: `then` is not a block, it's a normal method call. (No special syntax sauce). And it doesn't "*return a promise resolved with 1*", it returns a promise that will resolve/reject with some not-yet-determined value *later*.

Comment: No, it does not deal with them in the same way, but returning an already-fulfilled promise will have the same end result as returning a plain value, yes.

Comment: @Bergi All understood ^^ thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All values returned from a `then` block are implicitly wrapped in a `Promise.resolve`, so returning `Promise.resolve(1)` is unnecessary.

Comment: As in, yes the two are equivalent? ^^

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent.